# Django - Form Not Saving Image on Form Submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

For my current ModelForm for some reason all the fields get updated on a form submission as they are supposed to except for the `image` field.

What’s the best solution to get this working with my current code?

I think it’s because `request.FILES` isn’t getting handled correctly in my `views.py` file but not 100% sure.

**Side note:** If i upload an image to the Django backend, the image field updates how it’s supposed to. This is only happening when there’s a form submission on the front end when the image field isn’t getting updated.

Below is my code.

Screenshots attached of the Django admin backend and the front end where the data is being displayed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

**views.py**

```
def account_view_myaccount_edit(request):
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    instance = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            listing_instance.user = user 
            listing_instance.save() 
            return redirect('myaccount_edit')  # Redirect to a success page
    else:
        form = HomeForm(instance=instance)
    
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'form': form
        }

    return render(request, 'myaccount_edit.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class User_Info(models.Model):

  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
  image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)
  user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=100)      
  zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
  mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

  class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = "User Info"
```

**forms.py**

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image  = forms.ImageField(required=True, label=_("image"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'file', 'id': 'upload-btn', 'accept': 'image/gif, image/jpg'}))
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control info-details'}))
    address = forms.CharField(required=True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control info-details'}))
    city = forms.CharField(required=True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control info-details'}))
    state = forms.CharField(required=True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control info-details'}))
    zip_code = forms.CharField(required=True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control info-details'}))
    mobile_number = forms.CharField(required=True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control info-details'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = User_Info
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', 'image']
```

**myaccount_edit.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.errors }}   
    <p>Name</p>
    {{ form.name }}
    <p>Address</p>
    {{ form.address }}
    <p>City</p>
    {{ form.city }}
    <p>State</p>
    {{ form.state }} 
     <p>Zip Code</p>
    {{ form.zip_code }}
    <p>Mobile Number</p>
    {{ form.mobile_number }}
    <p>Upload Profile Photo</p>
    {{ form.image }}
    <br/>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-round btn-accept" type="submit" value="Submit"><i class="zmdi zmdi-favorite-outline6"></i>Submit</button>
    <br/>
    <a class="btn-cancel" href="{% url 'myaccount' %}">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

**base.html - this is template where the profile image is being displayed.**

```
                  <div class="profile-image-side">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    {% for profile in user_profile %}
                    <img src="{{ profile.image.url }}" >
                    <p class="m-b-0">{{ user.username }}</p>                            
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you already set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in **settings.py**?  If in development, add `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to **urls.py**.  Finally try changing `{{ form.image }}` to `{{ form.image.url }}`.

Comment: @raphael Yes. I already added set ``media_root`` and ``media_url`` in settings.. I just changed the form to  ``{{ form.image.url }}`` and now the file upload disappeared. I also tested added ``+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`` with no luck.. What can I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: @raphael I updated the images and added ``base.html`` which where the template where the image is being displayed. Also I tried debugging by adding ``User_Info.image = request.FILES.get('image',instance)`` under ``if form.is_valid():`` and got ``'str' object has no attribute 'url'``.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Still working on it.  For some reason, removing the line `image  = forms.ImageField(required=True, label=_("image"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'file', 'id': 'upload-btn', 'accept': 'image/gif, image/jpg'}))` works.  I also tried setting `required=False` and while that did prevent the form from producing errors, it did not save the image.  And leave the template with `{{ form.image }}`.

Comment: @raphael Holy crap! It worked on my end too when that line was commented out.  So strange. Looks like it's something with widgets. I appreciate it so much. I'm trying to debug too right now. I appreciate it so much!

Comment: @raphael Solved it! Looks like in forms ``TextInput`` doesn't play nice with ``forms.ImageField``.  I hardcoded the input field in the html and now it works just fine. ``<input type="file" id="upload-btn" name="image" type="submit" value="" accept="image/gif, image/jpg">``

Comment: @raphael You're a ninja! Thanks again for taking a look at it. I appreciate it a ton!

Answer (score 1):

After debugging, I added the below to `myaccount_edit.html` and removed `{{ form.image }}`

`<input type="file" id="upload-btn" name="image" type="submit" value="" accept="image/gif, image/jpg">`

In my `forms.py` file,

`image  = forms.ImageField(required=True, label=_("image"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'file', 'id': 'upload-btn', 'accept': 'image/gif, image/jpg'}))`

`TextInput` wasn't playing nice with `ImageField` since it's I'm guessing i'm passing an image not text. This can be a common mistake maybe so it's a small detail that can be missed. Thanks for the help!